# How to efficiently combine pandas dataframes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

- I have 2 dataframes, df_oth and df_small.
- The 'ID' column uniquely identifies each row in df_oth.
- In df_small on the other hand, each ID might feature more than once.

I'm trying to

- extract contents of some columns from df_small for each ID
- convert them to lists and wrap in dictionaries
- finally, store in a new column on df_oth, under the corresponding ID.

In my first iteration, I was assigning df_row to the corresponding cell on df_oth but this was too slow. Then, I modified the code as below to store the combined values in a temporary dataframe and then push to df_oth at the end. It got a bit quicker but still,, each 1K operation still takes roughly 4s and I have around 1M unique IDs. So, I'd really appreciate some pointers regarding how to do this quicker? Using parallelisation or another library like Dask etc, isn't an option, so, I'll have to stick to Pandas.

```
sum_t1, sum_t2 = 0,0
ratio = 1000
df_oth.set_index('ID')
df_oth.sort_index()
df_temp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'newcol'])
df_temp.set_index('ID')
grps = df_small.groupby('ID')
idx = 0
for grp, frame in grps:
    s1 = time.time()
    idx += 1
    id_no = frame.iloc[0, frame.columns.get_loc('ID')]
    df_row = pd.DataFrame({'ID': id_no, 
                           'newcol': [
                                       {'C1_Arr': frame['C1'], 
                                       'C2_Arr': frame['C2']}
                                      ]})
    s2 = time.time()
    df_temp = df_temp.append(df_row, ignore_index=True)
    t1, t2 = (s2 - s1), (time.time() -s2)
    sum_t1 += t1
    sum_t2 += t2
    if idx % ratio == 0:
        print(f'{idx}: {ser_no} - {sum_t1} - {sum_t2} - {sum_t1 / sum_t2}')
        sum_t1, sum_t2 = 0,0\
df_temp.sort_index()
df_oth = pd.merge(df_oth, df_temp, on='ID')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,it took a lot of trial and error but here are the lessons learnt

- Instead of pushing rows to a data frame on each iteration, add rows to a list and append to the df in one gone right at the end
- Any referencing via [], loc and iloc are quite expensive, so, instead of extracting the columns by`frame['Cx']`, `iloc[:, n:]` works much better. The column order can be changed right before the loop to keep the desired ones aligned to one side.
- Operations like `reset_index` and `drop` on the group element on each loop are expensive too.

I don't have the full stats but after these simple modifications, running time comes from projected ~1+h to 2 minutes.

```
temp_lst = list()
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'newcol'])
grps = df_small.groupby('ID')
for grp_name, frame in grps:
    temp_lst.append({'ID': grp_name, 'newcol': 
        list(frame.iloc[:, 1:].T.to_dict().values())})
df_tmp = df_temp.append(df_row, ignore_index=True)
df_oth = df_oth.merge(df_temp, how='left', on='ID')
```